# NodeJs Events and making algorithms

Tags: node.js, events

I need to write a command-line utility. Depending on the user's choice utility will run a certain algorithm. Algorithm must be modular and consisted of a specified set of tasks. Tasks will be implemented in the form of modules, wich will be linked by event model.

A simple example below

```
// main.js
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

let _first = require('./first');
let _second = require('./second');
let map = new Map();

map.set('first', new _first(myEmitter));
map.set('second', new _second(myEmitter));

myEmitter.emit('start', 3);

// first.js
module.exports = function First(Emiter) {
    Emiter.on('start', (x) => {
      console.log('an event occurred! in First. get: ' + x++);
      Emiter.emit('next', x);
    });
}

// second.js
module.exports = function Second(Emiter) {
    Emiter.on('next', (x) => {
      console.log('an event occurred! in Second, get: ' + x);
    });
}
```

Is this right way? Is there any negative points use handler-functions in the constructor?